# Clear the command screen in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any command in Gnuplot which works as 'cls' on DOS?

I'm not talking about 'clear'. I just want to erase the writen command lines, not the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which OS you are using and how you are working with gnuplot.

On windows, if you are using the gui terminal (wgnuplot.exe), I believe the answer is no.

If you are working with a terminal from the shell/command prompt (gnuplot.exe on windows), you can use whatever your shell clear command is with the system command.

On windows, you can type `system 'cls'` and it will clear the screen.  On linux, using `system 'clear'` will have the same effect.